# Are we allowed to ride a geared motorcycle(2 wheeler) alone on indian roads with a learner's license

Tags: india, traffic, driving

I have a learner's license for a geared bike in India. And I want to know if according to indian governmental laws, can a citizen ride a geared bike alone with a learner's license.

I tried searching this on the web and came across [this discussion](https://www.quora.com/I-have-a-learners-license-for-a-two-wheeler-in-India-Is-it-legal-for-me-to-drive-the-vehicle-alone-i-e-without-a-permanent-license-holder-as-a-pillion) where some people claim that it is allowed. Below I've quoted one statement from the mentioned discussion:

> Simply put,
>
> For 2 wheelers - **Yes. Its legal to ride “alone”.** If you have a person in pillion, He/she should be with valid permanent driving licence.
>
> For 4 wheelers - No. You cannot drive alone But only with a person with valid permanent driving licence.
>
> In both Bike and car, ‘L’ sign is mandatory in front and backside of vehicle(Red on white format).

(emphasis mine)

As we can see, the author of the above comment claims that it is legal for a 2 wheeler. But in the same discussion some other people say that it is illegal.

So I want to know whether it is legal or illegal as per indian govt. laws to ride a 2 wheeler alone with a learner's license. Basically, I want a **authoritative reference** to some clause(s) from where we can find whether it is allowed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule 3 of [The Central Motor Vehicle Rules, 1988](https://morth.nic.in/sites/default/files/CMVR-chapter2.pdf) prescribe the conditions as per which an individual holding a license (as per Section 3 of the Motor Vehicles Act, 1988) can drive the vehicle.

The relevant portion of the Rules pertaining to your query reads as follows:

> "3. General. - The provisions of sub-section *(1) of section 3 shall
> not apply to a person while receiving instructions or gaining
> experience in driving with the object of presenting himself for a test
> of competence to drive, **so long as**— (a) such person is the holder of
> an effective learner's licence issued to him in Form 3 to drive the
> vehicle; (b) **such person is accompanied by an instructor holding an
> effective driving License to drive the vehicle and such instructor is
> sitting in such a position to control or stop the vehicle**; and
>
> ...
>
> Provided that a person, while receiving instructions or gaining
> experience in driving a motor cycle (with or without a side-car
> attached), shall not carry any other person on the motor cycle
> except for the purpose and in the manner referred to in clause (b)"

Hence, **as a person with a learning license, you can only ride a motor cycle if you take a person as a pillion**, and such person must be an instructor with a driving license for a motor cycle sitting in a position to control or stop the vehicle.